# how many std::string copies are being made?

Tags: c++, string

```
string str1("someString");
string str2 = string(str1);//how many copies are made here
    //copy2 = copy1?
```

When you assign a string with string(otherString), does it copy the value in the parentheses then copy that value to the variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In real life there will be one copy, though theoretically it depends on the version of the language your compiler implements.

`string(str1)` is going to create a temporary that's a copy of `str1`.

In C++98/03, the compiler will theoretically use copy initialization to initialize `str2` from that temporary, so in theory a second copy will be made at that point. In reality, you'll probably have a hard time finding a compiler that doesn't elide one of those copy operations though (at least if optimization is enabled).

In C++11, `std::string` has a move constructor (one that takes an rvalue reference), which should be used to initialize `str2`, so the second copy shouldn't even theoretically happen.

Answer (score 9):

Technically there can be two copies, but in real life you are doing just one copy. That is, the compiler will realize that the temporary is not needed and optimize away the copy.